# Kafka topic retenrtion.ms works strange

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-topic

I want to configure topic level retention on my kafka.
So I set log.roll.ms to 6000

```
kafka-configs.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --entity-type topics --entity-name retantion_test_topic --describe
Dynamic configs for topic retantion_test_topic are:
  retention.ms=6000 sensitive=false synonyms={DYNAMIC_TOPIC_CONFIG:retention.ms=6000}
```

after this I create some messages in this topic

```
kafka-console-producer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic retantion_test_topic
```

expected behavior that after 6 seconds I will launch consumer-group cli and those messages will not be consumed. But when I launch

```
kafka-console-consumer.sh --topic retantion_test_topic --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --group retantion_test_group
```

I see all the messages.

so then I repeated all again but waited a lot more (5 minutes) and launched `kafka-console-consumer` again. Now I don't see messages, because they are marked as deleted I suppose. But what is strange, is that when I create a couple of messages, wait 5 minutes, and create another couple of messages and run `kafka-console-consumer` again, I expect to see the latest messages to be consumed, because they are created just immediately before launching `kafka-console-consumer`. They are not older than 6 seconds, but I can't see them. I repeated the experiment with retention.ms equals 1 minute. Same result. The messages for the last 1 minute and all older messages were not consumed. Can you help me to understand why?

Comment: Kafka only deletes segments of topic logs, not individual messages. Providing a group will commit offsets, so you won't consume them again without resetting that